# docker + openshift. How to use only private registry?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, openshift

Expand RED HAT CONTAINER REGISTRY with a local Docker image repository.

As a Docker user, I can work with the registry (pull, push) everything is OK!

But also, as a user, I can upload an image with the docker hub with the pull command.

For example:

> $ docker pull debian

Question:

How to prevent the user to "pull" the image with docker hub and allow using only the openshift internal registry?

Those. Is it possible to configure any config so that the user accesses the internal repository of images?